# Technique to create new var foo=new{bar = "Hohoho"}

Tags: c#, var, massive

I am new to the c# language and questions came up.
i use the massive single file DB.

here you can create a class like this:

```
public class products : DynamicModel 
{
    public products(String conn) : base("northwind", "products","productid") 
    {
    }
}
```

now would i do sth like this:

```
var products = new { Productname = "HOHOHO" };
```

until here everything works fine, but i want to query and update different databases and tables and so i dont know that there is a table column like "Productname" so this must be a variable:

```
string foo = "Productname";
var products = new { foo = "HOHOHO" };
```

But this would leed to the fact that the massive looks for a column "foo" because the string would not be interpreted.

How can I insert a variable here?

How is this technique named?

thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to TGH!

In combination with the massive DB the use of an NameValueCollection would solve the problem:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add(field, (string)fieldValue);
table.Update(nvc, keyValue);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables when defining properties on your anonymous objects.
I would recommend that you look into a `Dictionary<string,string>` to represent this instead. A Dictionary/Hashtable is probably the most flexible way to get around the static nature of c# when it comes to dynamic variables

You can let each column name be the keys in the dictionary

Comment: thank you for your answer - this could help. but i get {[key,val]} instead of {key,val} any further suggestions?